# Which spring-test jar version to use with Spring Integration

Tags: maven, spring-integration, spring-test

We are using Spring Integration version 2.2.0.RC2.

When running tests, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org/springframework/core/type/classreading/AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor
```

I understand this is because of a clash of Spring jars, likely due to the wrong version in the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When using Spring Integration version 2.2.0.RC2, which version of spring-tests should be used? Furthermore, what is the best way to resolve these kind of Maven clashes in future - is there a listing of compatible versions of Spring jars?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a very old SI release candidate? - it's not a release. The current version of 2.2.x is 2.2.6

Comment: As far as I can see from mvn dependency:tree, when using Spring Integration 2.2.6 it brings in Spring jars version 3.1.3, and that conflicts with the 3.2.4 jars which spring-test 3.2.4 is bringing in:  [INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.3.RELEASE:compile

Comment: 3.1.3 is simply the minimum requirement for SI; we run nightly builds with 3.2.x - simply exclude the transitive dependencies in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

If you a do a `mvn dependency:tree` are there any org.springframework:spring-core libraries in there that are not at the expected levels?

Run that and make sure your spring version numbers are ALL consistent. Use `dependencyManagement` stanzas to ensure they're consistent.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117790/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-deploying-a-war-file-that-was-created-by-ma) had the same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

We run a nightly build of SI against Spring 3.2.x; 3.1.3 is simply the minimum supported dep. To use a newer version of Spring, you can `<exclude/>` the transitive dependencies in your POM.